# Eclipse keeps deleting necessary XSD imports

Tags: xml, eclipse, import, xsd

I'm editing XSD files in eclipse.
When saving, eclipse keeps removing necessary imports from my file. Why? This phenomenon doesn't occur for every XSD so I assume a mistake on my side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema
    targetNamespace="abc"

    xmlns:kei="kdf"
    xmlns:neo="neoNS"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    version="1.0"
>

    <xsd:import namespace="kdf" schemaLocation="mycomp.kdf.xsd" />
    <!-- the next one gets removed on save -->
    <xsd:import namespace="neoNS" schemaLocation="mycomp.anExistingFile.xsd" />
  <!-- ****************************************************************** -->
  <xs:complexType name="initialisiereAngebotType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="kei:messageHeader"/>
      <xs:element name="payload" type="neo:initialisiereAngebotRequestType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

I can even use Ctrl+LMB to jump into the existing file. And I need the import for the payload element, so why is it deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Probably have something to do with this option :

`Window > Preferences > XML > XML Schema Files > Editor`

`Automatically remove unused XSD imports and XML Namespace entries`

Try uncheck it and see if thats works.

Comment: It doesn't get thrown out, yet it doesn't explain why he identifies this very line as unused (while it is used, just as the other import)